# Unable to import counter from collections in python 3 anaconda python in windows 10

Tags: python-3.x

whenever I try to do this "from collections import counter", I am getting output as follows plz let me know why?

ImportError: cannot import name 'counter' from 'collections' (C:\Users\chandra teja\Anaconda3\lib\collections__init__.py)

Process finished with exit code 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `from collections import Counter` Note the UPPER-CASE `"C"`
good luck